# Having issues creating a table of objects in a loop. Every item in the table is the last item! Lua

Tags: lua

So I've created a sample program to illustrate a real program that I can't share.

My sample program has a `Float` object. The Float object holds the integer side and the decimal side.

I have a loop that will create 10 Floats and add them to a numbers table.

When I print out the numbers table, ever item in it is the last item created. I of course want each item to be its own self.

I feel this bug is because of Lua's pass-by-reference model for objects, and I must not have the 'class' set up correctly.

Sample code:

```
-- Float class

Float = { int = 0, decimal = 0 }
function Float:new(o, i, d) 
    o = o or {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    self.int = i
    self.decimal =  d 
    return o
end

function Float:print()
    print(self.int.."."..self.decimal)
end
-- Float class end

-- driver code
numbers = {}
function main()

    for i = 0, 10, 1 do
        -- this weird indexing is because in my real program I will be indexing w/ a string so I wanted to mimic that
        numbers["a"..i] = Float:new(nil, i, i)
    end

    for k,v in pairs(numbers) do
        print(v:print())
    end

end

main()
```

Output:

```
10.10

10.10

10.10

10.10

10.10

10.10

10.10

10.10

10.10

10.10

10.10
```

Expected Output (but out of order since pairs() function):

```
1.1
2.2
3.3
4.4
5.5
6.6
7.7
8.8
9.9
10.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` in `Float:new(nil,i,i)` refers to `Float`, not to `o`.

So, use

```
o.int = i
o.decimal =  d
```

instead of

```
self.int = i
self.decimal =  d
```